# caliburn.micro 2 BindableAppBar Silverlight 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

i have a caliburn micro 2 in a project Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight.
How to use a BindableApplicationBar?
if i add

```
 xmlns:bab="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro.BindableAppBar;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.BindableAppBar"
```

not it works and in a NuGet Package not exists a package with BindableAppBar 2,0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BindableAppBar isn't part of Caliburn.Micro it's a separate project https://github.com/kamranayub/CaliburnBindableAppBar